# Probability of getting exactly one pair in a poker hand when the first two cards drawn are of different denominations.

Tags: probability

I’m trying to find the probability of getting exactly one pair in a poker hand when it’s given that the first two cards drawn are of different denominations. I’m stuck on the fact that you could draw a card of the same denomination as one of the first two cards, but can’t draw both. You could also draw the other 3 cards and get a pair that doesn’t involve the first two cards. I get how to get the probability of getting just one pair but am stuck on this one. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Let us use the letters A, B for the first two cards. Then all matching configurations can be easily listed, they are ABACD, ABCAD, ABCDA; ABBCD, ABCBD, ABCDB; ABCCD, ABCDC, ABDCC. Now we count the many cases to realize each situation in the list.

Comment: @dan_fulea "*can be easily listed*"... one of the purposes of an introductory course on counting is how to count *without* resorting to using lists and counting with our fingers as that is prone to error, either by counting incorrectly or by having forgotten or duplicated an item in the list.

Comment: @JMoravitz There was no claim about having a purely combinatorial solution, which is of course simple for someone who solved many problems of this kind. In our case there is no course specified in the OP, rather only "*I’m trying to find the probability of getting exactly one pair in a poker hand...*" and there seems to be a problem in organizing the combinatorial data. Now when you closer look at the "list" in the comment, just notice the usage of comma and semicolon, this gives enough combinatorial information, so it is a combinatorial hint. I will type the solution then...

Answer (score 3):

Given the first two cards that you have drawn, there are $\binom{50}{3}$ equally likely remaining collections of cards you can draw.

Of these, to get a pair we may either reuse one of the already used ranks, or we may pull a pair within the three cards that we newly draw.

Had we reused an already existing rank, there are $6$ choices for which card that is.  There are $\binom{11}{2}$ ways to choose the remaining two ranks, and $4$ choices for each suit used for a total of $6\times \binom{11}{2}\times 4^2$ possible outcomes here.

Had we not reused an already existing rank, then there are $11$ choices for which rank we get a pair in, $\binom{4}{2}$ for which suits are used for that pair, and then $10\times 4$ choices for the final card for a total of $11\times \binom{4}{2}\times 10\times 4$ possible outcomes in this case.

This gives a final total of:

$$\dfrac{6\times \binom{11}{2}\times 4^2 + 11\times \binom{4}{2}\times 10\times 4}{\binom{50}{3}}=\dfrac{99}{245}\approx 0.40408$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote by $A,B$ the first two cards, and $X,Y,Z$ the next three cards.

Let $\Omega_0=\{1,2,3,\dots,13\}\times\{\diamondsuit,\heartsuit,\spadesuit,\clubsuit\}$ be the set of all cards. We denote by $n(C)$ the "number" on the card $C$.

The space where we compute the probability is
$$\Omega =\Big\{\ (A,B,X,Y,Z)\in \Omega_0^5\ :\ \text{ Cardinality of $\{A,B,X,Y,Z\}$ is five and $n(A)\ne n(B)$ }\ \Big\}\ .$$
On it we consider the maximal $\sigma$-algebra (of all its subsets), and the uniform probability $\Bbb P$.
We consider the event:
$$E =\Big\{\ (A,B,X,Y,Z)\in \Omega\subset \Omega_0^5\ :\ \text{ Cardinality of $\{n(A),n(B),n(X),n(Y),n(Z)\}$ is four }\ \Big\}\ .$$

We need to compute $\Bbb P(E)=|E|/|\Omega|$. So we only have to compute the cardinalities $|E|$, $|\Omega|$. The last is simple:
$$
\Omega=52\cdot(52-4)\cdot(52-2)\cdot(52-3)\cdot(52-4)\ .
$$

---

**First solution:**
For the cardinality of $E$, we may consider the set $F$ given by
$$F =\Big\{\ (C,D,X,Y,Z)\in \Omega_0^5\ :\ \text{ Cardinality of $\{n(C),n(D),n(X),n(Y),n(Z)\}$ is four }\ \Big\}\ .$$
It is not included in $\Omega$. And we can simpler get $|F|$ using the following counting technique. We fix an element $\xi=(C,D,X,Y,Z)\in F$. Let $1\le j<k\le 5$ be the two positions in $\xi$ for the two cards with the same number. Of course, $j=j_\xi, k=k_\xi$ depend on $\xi$. We can split $F$ correspondingly in the pieces $F_{jk}$, where now $1\le j<k\le 5$ do not depend on anything, and count the elements in $F_{jk}$ by looking first at the positions $j,k$. This gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
|F|&=\sum_{1\le j<k\le 5}|F_{jk}| 
\\
&=\sum_{1\le j<k\le 5}52\cdot 3\cdot(52-4)\cdot(52-8)\cdot(52-12)
\\
&=\binom 52\cdot52\cdot 3\cdot(52-4)\cdot(52-8)\cdot(52-12)\ .
\\[3mm]
&\text{ Now }E=F\cap \Omega=F-F_{12}\ ,\\
|E|&=\sum_{\substack{1\le j<k\le 5\\(j,k)\ne(1,2)}}|F_{jk}|
\\
&=\left(\binom 52-1\right)\cdot52\cdot 3\cdot(52-4)\cdot(52-8)\cdot(52-12)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In fact, a "direct" solution would start with the above number in the numerator, and $|\Omega|$ in the denominator, as is often happens:

> $$
> \Bbb P(E)=
> \frac
> {\left(\binom 52-1\right)\cdot52\cdot 3\cdot(52-4)\cdot(52-8)\cdot(52-12)}
> {52\cdot(52-4)\cdot(52-2)\cdot(52-3)\cdot(52-4)}
> =
> \frac{99}{245}\approx 0.404081632653\dots\ .
> \ .
> $$

---

**Second solution:** We count explicitly.
Let us use now the letters $A, B$ for the **numbers** (or figures) on the first two cards. Different letters always stay for cards with different "numbers" on the cards. Then all matching configurations / patterns  can be easily listed, as the OP wants, and i always encourage didactically to force a full solution completing the own thoughts. The matching configurations are

- $ABACD$, $ABCAD$, $ABCDA$, where $A$ repeats on positions $3,4,5$ respectively,
- $ABBCD$, $ABCBD$, $ABCDB$, where $B$ repeats on positions $3,4,5$ respectively,
- $ABCCD$, $ABCDC$, $ABDCC$, where $C$ repeats on two positions among $3,4,5$ respectively. Using this counting, the probability is:

> $$
> \frac
> {(3+3+3)\cdot52\cdot 3\cdot(52-4)\cdot(52-8)\cdot(52-12)}
> {52\cdot(52-4)\cdot(52-2)\cdot(52-3)\cdot(52-4)}
> =
> \frac{99}{245}\approx 0.404081632653\dots\ .
> \ .
> $$

---

Brute force computer check, we assume the first two cards are fixed to avoid stack overflow:

```
sage: Cards = cartesian_product( [[1..13], [1..4]] )
sage: Omega = [ ( (1,1), (2,1), c, d, e ) 
....:           for c in Cards
....:           for d in Cards
....:           for e in Cards ]
sage: Omega = [ (a,b,c,d,e) for (a,b,c,d,e) in Omega
....:           if len({a,b,c,d,e}) == 5 and a[0] != b[0] ]
sage: E = [ (a,b,c,d,e) for (a,b,c,d,e) in Omega 
....:       if len({a[0], b[0], c[0], d[0], e[0]}) == 4 ]
sage: len(E) / len(Omega)
0
sage: ZZ(len(E)) / len(Omega)
99/245
sage: _.n()
0.404081632653061
```